# Solr index custom file types

Tags: solr

Basically, I am a Solr newbie and have had 0 experience with this as our Solr expert left the company.  We are receiving a file from a client that is a proprietary file.  I don't have access to the application in which it was generated from.

When uploading to Solr we receive the following error

```
SOLR Log
solr-cloud.log: {"msg":"2022-01-19 08:10:06.915 ERROR (qtp349420578-3516) [c:<collection> s:shard2 r:core_node5 x:<redacted>] o.a.s.s.HttpSolrCall null:java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ucar/nc2/NetcdfFile"}

Our App logging
org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient$RemoteSolrException: Error from server at http://localhost:8983/solr/<collection>: Expected mime type application/octet-stream but got text/html. <html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>
<title>Error 500 Server Error</title>
</head>
<body><h2>HTTP ERROR 500</h2>
<p>Problem accessing /solr/<collection>/update/extract. Reason:
<pre>    Server Error</pre></p><h3>Caused by:</h3><pre>java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ucar/nc2/NetcdfFile
        at org.apache.tika.parser.hdf.HDFParser.parse(HDFParser.java:88)
        at org.apache.tika.parser.CompositeParser.parse(CompositeParser.java:280)
```

Other normal file types works (e.g. doc, pdf, zip)

1. I cannot open or edit the file to see what fields are in there to
   index so is there a way to be able to index this?
2. If not, is there anything else I can do to handle this file type

TIA

Comment: Solar support only few file format for text indexing. What file format you are pushing for indexing? You can check with Tika as well. Apache Tika can be integrated with solar to support more file format or text indexing.

Comment: @AbhijitBashetti thanks for your reply this is a gnet file type.  I will look at Tika.  Do you know if there is a list somewhere that specifies which types are supported?

Comment: Please check here https://tika.apache.org/2.2.1/formats.html

Comment: @AbhijitBashetti so that file is listed there.  How do I have this in Solr?

Comment: check this link if further steps...https://solr.apache.org/guide/7_7/uploading-data-with-solr-cell-using-apache-tika.html#:~:text=Solr%20uses%20code%20from%20the,for%20data%20extraction%20and%20indexing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

file is being parsed by Solr/Tika using an HDF parser which in turn depends on NetCDF parser -
https://www.unidata.ucar.edu/downloads/netcdf-java/